# Does Android have a means to store a string that can be retrieved after a factory reset?

Tags: android

I'm trying to assure that a device ID for an Android device stays consistent, even after factory resets. I realize I can't assure it will always be unique so this is an exercise in best efforts.

In the iOS world you can do this by grabbing or making a unique ID and storing it into the Keychain, which survives past app deletions and more.

Is there a comparable way to have a persistent, unique device ID for an Android device?

Comment: Some people don't like being tracked this way, but: use the IMEI ?

Comment: Do you really need to uniquely identify the device itself, or do you just want to identify the user?

Comment: This will be used to assure that our provisioned hardware is being used. That means I need to track the hardware ID itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android id.

```
String androidId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: That can change with resets so it doesn't help me.